# Complete file path of multiple Excel workbooks with Python

Tags: python, xlwings

I have multiple Excel workbooks open on my computer, which are in different instances. I am using the following script to get the complete path of all the files.

With below code I can get only a list of file names. How can I get the full path?

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.books
print (wb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Book` object has a [`fullname`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=books#xlwings.Book.fullname) property:

```py
import xlwings

workbooks = xlwings.books
for workbook in workbooks:
    print(workbook.fullname)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full path of opened(active) excel file by using this:
If you want then here's the [docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=books#xlwings.Book.fullname), you can explore other options also from docs.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.books.active
print(wb.fullname)
"""
C:\Users\...\Desktop\Book1.xlsx
"""
```

But if you want to get path of all files then:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb= xw.books
for w in wb:
    print(w.fullname)
"""
C:\Users\...\Desktop\Book1.xlsx
C:\Users\...\Desktop\Book2.xlsx
C:\Users\...\Desktop\Book3.xlsx
"""
```